# Change label height of custom cell within didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to resize a label's height when my custom cell is selected (to allow it to expand so more text is visible).

I'm obviously missing something fundamental though because the frame is the exact same after I try to draw the new CGRect.

Here's the relevant code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! BasicCell
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        currentCell.subtitleLabel!.frame = CGRectMake(currentCell.subtitleLabel!.frame.origin.x, currentCell.subtitleLabel!.frame.origin.y, currentCell.subtitleLabel!.frame.size.width, 100)
        currentCell.subtitleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try add a Bool to your custom cell and in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method set the height to the cells contentSize.height otherwise tableView.rowHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

inside `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` pair. Simply setting the frame is not enough for table view to know which cell needs to be updated.

Also there's no need to put your update code inside animation block. It's animated inherently.

Comment: So incidentally I had tried `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` before and thought it wasn't working because the label doesn't seem to update. But going back and checking the frames, it does indeed change the frame. Now I have to figure out what's going on with the label not updating. Thanks for the answer.